# Pole/Zero Cancellation and Observability

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider the following system:

$
\dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}u
$

$
y = \begin{bmatrix}
1&
1
\end{bmatrix}x
$

Now, one of the eigenvalues of this system is $0$. Clearly, in the transfer function, this pole is cancelled by a zero. Furthermore, for this example, both modes of the system are observable.

In this [source](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/course/2/2.151/www/Handouts/Controllability.pdf), the following statement is given:

[image]

According to this, since there is a zero/pole cancellation, the mode $0$ should be unobservable. What am I missing in here? Can you explain when there is a zero/pole cancellation in a system, how observability and controllability is affected?

Comment: Because of the lack of controllability. The mode zero is not controllable. When there are poles/zeros cancellations, we lose either controllability, or observability, or both.

Comment: There is a typo in your source. There should be no matrix B in the first transfer function.

Comment: For example, if there is zero/pole cancellation in the transfer function, then can we say that the cancelled mode is uncontrollable? Or at the output, if there is one mode missing, then can we say that that mode is unobservable?

Comment: "When there are poles/zeros cancellations, we lose either controllability, or observability, or both". How can we decide when we lose both or only one of them?

Comment: One could use the [Hautus lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautus_lemma) or the [Kalman decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_decomposition) to check whether a mode loses both or only one.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen actually this question was related to our previous discussion in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531237/inferring-the-state-space-form.  In that question, you were able to say controllable and observable modes immediately. However, in order to use Hautus lemma, we need to know $A$ and $B$. So, if you know only the output and the transfer function, then how do you decide the mode properties immediately?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen in your previous comment, you did not utilize the transfer function. What I am asking is to utilize the pole/zero cancellation information.

Comment: @eet Yes, it is a mode that is observable or controllable. You can verify the loss of observability using the PBH test (as Kwin said) or the rank drop in the matrices $\begin{bmatrix}sI-A & B\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}sI-A\\C\end{bmatrix}$ at the mode $s$ for the controllability and the observability, respectively.

Comment: It is also immediate to see from this example, that the first state is not controllable since one has $\dot{x}_1=0$ no matter what $u$ is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with such a cancellation for controllability is that the control input U(s) can no longer influence the state of the system associated with the cancelled pole. This results in a loss of control over that part of the state space, rendering the system uncontrollable. I just rephrased what the book said. Same for observability.